# Map_Kd not passed correclty in mtl file

Tags: export

The picture pretty much sums up the problem :

[image]

Two of my materials have this problem and I can't work around why that is so. Every other material has the path of the texture of the texture file as it should. Here we only see a dot instead. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender allows us to [pack image and other data files](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/introduction.html) into the blend file.

An image texture that is packed into a blend file and not saved to disk, will export to .obj with `map_Kd .` in the .mtl file.

The solution is to view the image in blenders UV/Image editor and save it out to a file. *Image->Save As Image* or press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

You can also use *File->External Data->Unpack All Into Files* to unpack multiple files in one go.